# Is there a Python's defaultdict functionality available in Lua

Tags: python, lua, defaultdict

Is there a functionality in Lua similar to [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) available in Python, which automatically handles default values for non-existent associative array keys?

I want the code below to set `nil` to `v` instead of an error. So basically a way to `a[2]` (non-existent key) be a `table` by default:

```
a = {}
v = a[2][3] 

>>> PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (main.lua:603: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value))
```

In Python it can be done like this:

```
>>> import collections
>>> a = collections.defaultdict(dict)
>>> print a[2]
{}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a Lua standard function to do it? No. But you can do it easily enough with metatables. You can even write a function to create such tables:

```
function CreateTableWithDefaultElement(default)
  local tbl = {}
  local mtbl = {}
  mtbl.__index = function(tbl, key)
    local val = rawget(tbl, key)
    return val or default
  end
  setmetatable(tbl, mtbl)
  return tbl
end
```

Note that each element will get the *same* default value. So if you make the default value a table, each "empty" element in the returned table will effectively reference the same table. If that's not what you want, you'll have to modify the function.

Comment: Why is rawget() necessary here? Won't __index() function be called only if table doesn't have requested key?

Answer (score 3):

just thought that I would share my version of this code, if anyone finding this needs a version compatible with tables, objects, et cetera. Also, as opposed to Nicol's solution, this actually creates the requested entries in the table.

```
function defaultdict(default_value_factory)
    local t = {}
    local metatable = {}
    metatable.__index = function(t, key)
        if not rawget(t, key) then
            rawset(t, key, default_value_factory(key))
        end
        return rawget(t, key)
    end
    return setmetatable(t, metatable)
end
```

Example usage:

```
d = defaultidct(function() return {} end)
table.insert(d["people"], {"Bob", "The Builder"})

names = defaultdict(function(key) return key end)
print(names["bob"]) -- bob
names["bob"] = "bob the builder"
names["ashley"] = "ashley the fire princess"
```